# Deleting a row from datatable, then the database is not updated

Tags: database, dataset, sql-server-ce

Deleting a row from a datatable with the following syntax:

```
Dim expression As String = "FULLTAG = 'ITEMTAG'"
Dim row() As DataRow = MYDataSet.Tables("MYTABLE").Select(expression)
Dim row2 As DataRow = row(0)
row2.Delete()
IWDataSet.Tables("MYTABLE").AcceptChanges()
```

Then attempting to update the corresponding database file (.sdf) with the following:

```
Dim MYAdapter As New SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE", ConnStr)
SqlCommBuilder.DataAdapter = MYAdapter
MYAdapter.UpdateCommand = SqlCommBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
MYAdapter.Update(MYDataSet, "MYTABLE")
IWDataSet.AcceptChanges()
```

The corresponding database (.sdf) is not update, the row that should have been deleted, is still present in the database.

Some suggestions?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved by myself.

the error was in:

```
IWDataSet.Tables("MYTABLE").AcceptChanges()
```

The method AcceptChanges() removes in a permanent way rows from the table after deleting them, so it is equivalent to perform a Remove() method. At the time of updating the database (.sdf file), previously removed rows are no longer available to the DataAdapter for deletion from the .sdf file.

Following is the correct code:

Deleting the row:

```
IWDataSet.Tables("[MYTABLE]").Rows.Find(MYKEY).Delete()
```

Updating the databae (.sdf file):

```
Dim MYAdapter As New SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE", ConnStr)
SqlCommBuilder.DataAdapter = MYAdapter
MYAdapter.UpdateCommand = SqlCommBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
MYAdapter.InsertCommand = SqlCommBuilder.GetInsertCommand
MYAdapter.DeleteCommand = SqlCommBuilder.GetDeleteCommand
MYAdapter.Update(MYDataSet, "MYTABLE")
IWDataSet.AcceptChanges()
```